# QuickCheck for Smalltalk?

Tags: unit-testing, smalltalk, quickcheck

Is there a QuickCheck module for Smalltalk, especially for Gnu Smalltalk, Squeak, and/or Pharo?

[Wikipedia: QuickCheck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck)

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to what JUnit/NUnit provide with their Theory/Data test runners, together with random generation of test data?

Comment: Heh, here I was going to say "if there's a Common Lisp port of QuickCheck, a Smalltalk port would be doable". And then I saw the author name of cl-quickcheck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[There is now](https://github.com/mcandre/quicksmash).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an alternative implementation to mcandre's: [SqueakCheck](http://www.squeaksource.com/SqueakCheck/).

It adds a `TheoryTestCase` to SUnit, which permits one to write parameterised test cases. SqueakCheck attempts to automatically determine (based on messages sent to the parameter) what kind of object to give the theory, and a collection of data generators then craft such an object.